# 8 by 8 array correlate to printing on OLED screen in python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, python-imaging-library, infrared

[image]

Basically, I have this 8x8 array grid displaying temperature values in Celsius, as shown in the grid above. I am reading these values from an infrared sensor. As of now, I have accomplished my goal of being able to read the sensor values pick up on higher temperature values too, and display rectangles correlating to pixel size on an OLED screen. About the same size, you see on the image above. I have placed my code below:

```
def Correlate(Num):
  while True:
    Update_Temperature_Data = Read_raw_temp()
    print(Temperature_Data)
    
    ##########################First-Row########################
    if Update_Temperature_Data[0] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((80,1,85,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((80,1,85,8), outline=0, fill=0)
         
    if Update_Temperature_Data[1] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((85,1,91,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((85,1,91,8), outline=0, fill=0)
         
    if Update_Temperature_Data[2] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((91,1,97,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((91,1,97,8), outline=0, fill=0)
        
    if Update_Temperature_Data[3] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((97,1,103,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((97,1,103,8), outline=0, fill=0)
    
    if Update_Temperature_Data[4] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((103,1,109,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
     else:
         draw.rectangle((103,1,109,8), outline=0, fill=0)
         
    if Update_Temperature_Data[5] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((109,1,115,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((109,1,115,8), outline=0, fill=0)
        
    if Update_Temperature_Data[6] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((115,1,121,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((115,1,121,8), outline=0, fill=0)

        
    if Update_Temperature_Data[7] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((121,1,126,8), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((121,1,126,8), outline=0, fill=0)
        
    ######################Second-Row#############################
    if Update_Temperature_Data[8] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((80,8,85,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((80,8,85,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[9] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((85,8,91,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((85,8,91,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[10] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((91,8,97,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((91,8,97,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[11] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((97,8,103,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((97,8,103,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[12] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((103,8,109,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((103,1,109,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[13] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((109,8,115,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((109,8,115,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[14] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((115,8,121,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((115,8,121,16), outline=0, fill=0)

    if Update_Temperature_Data[15] > 27:
        draw.rectangle((121,8,126,16), fill=1, outline=0)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
    else:
        draw.rectangle((121,8,126,16), outline=0, fill=0)
```

As you can see I have a bunch of if-else statements for the first two rows, and it would be the same procedure for the following rows as well. But this definitely seems too tedious and has a lot of code to cover. I need help in finding a way to shorten the code and make this much simpler because it is repetitive. Any help would be great?

Comment: You could create a dictionary for each value on the display. Then using a for loop go through and find the value that matches what is in the dictionary then display it. Also instead of  if Update_Temperature_Data[0] you could do a for loop and do something like  if Update_Temperature_Data[var]

Comment: @thesonyman101 - thanks for your reply, I want this program to continously run forever using the while True, if I use the for loop to go through that dictionary, how do I reset the counter  for the loop after its finished going through the entire dictionary back to zero ? Or would that happen on its own becuase of the while True loop?

Comment: if you're using for I in x: then you do not need to reset the loop once it goes through all the indexes the while loop will restart it.

Comment: ok thanks @sonyman101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do. It's not a completed version of your code you will have to modify it to fit your needs.

```
  def Correlate(Num):
      Row1recs = {0:"""80,1,85,8""",1:"""85,1,91,8""",2:"""91,1,97,8""",3:"""97,1,103,8""",4:"""103,1,109,8""",}
      Row2recs = {0:"""80,1,85,8"""}
      elserecsrow1 = {0:"""103,1,109,8"""}
      elserecsrow2 = {0:"""103,1,109,8"""}
      while True:
          Update_Temperature_Data = Read_raw_temp()
          print(Temperature_Data)
          for i in Update_Temperature_Data:
              if Update_Temperature_Data[i] > 27:
                  draw.rectangle((eval(Row1recs[i])), fill=1, outline=0)
                  disp.image(image)
                  disp.display()
              else:
                  draw.rectangle((eval(Row2recs[i])), outline=0, fill=0)
              if Update_Temperature_Data[i] > 27:
                  draw.rectangle((eval(elserecsrow1[i])), fill=1, outline=0)
                  disp.image(image)
                  disp.display()
              else:
                  draw.rectangle((eval(elserecsrow2[i])), outline=0, fill=0)
```